# Average and variance of flipping a coin

Tags: probability, statistics

A coin is flipped repeatedly with probability $p$ of landing on heads each flip.

Calculate the average $\langle n\rangle$ and the variance $\sigma^2 = \langle n^2\rangle - \langle n\rangle^2$ of the attempt n at which heads appears for the first time.

I have absolutely no idea where to start. How does one calculate $\langle n \rangle$ and $\langle n^2\rangle$? I have probability that head appears for the first time on the $n^{th}$ attempt to be $p(1-p)^{n-1}$ if that helps.

edit: Does it work if I treat it like a binomial distribution? Although I still don't understand how the expectation and variance come about.

Answer (score 4):

This is a just a geometric distribution. If you aren't familiar with that, then I will derive the probability distribution. Let $X_n$ be iid $\operatorname{Ber}(p)$ random variables, i.e. $$\mathbb P(X_1=1)=p=1-\mathbb P(X_1=0),$$
and the $X_n$ are mutually independent. Then
$$X=\inf\{n\geqslant 1: X_n = 1\}. $$
For $n\geqslant 1$,
$$\mathbb P(X=n) = \mathbb P(X_{n}=1, X_{n-1}=0, \ldots, X_1=0). $$
Now, as the $X_n$ are independent, the above quantity is 
$$\mathbb P(X_{n}=1)\mathbb \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\mathbb P(X_i=0)=p\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(1-p)=p(1-p)^{n-1}. $$
Since
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X=n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{n-1} = p\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-p)^n = p\cdot\frac1{1-(1-p)}=1, $$
this is indeed a valid probability distribution. To compute the mean, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X] &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mathbb P(X=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty np(1-p)^{n-1}\\
&= p\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(1-p)^n\\
&= p\cdot\frac1{(1-(1-p))^2}\\
&= \frac1p.
\end{align*}$$
To compute the variance, it is easier to first compute $\mathbb E[X(X-1)]$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X(X-1)] &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n-1)p(1-p)^{n-1}\\
&= p(1-p)\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n+1)(1-p)^n\\
&= p(1-p)\cdot\frac2{p^3}\\
&= \frac{2(1-p)}{p^2}.
\end{align*}
$$

Hence

$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(X) &= \mathbb E[X^2] - \mathbb E[X]^2\\
&= \mathbb E[X(X-1)] + \mathbb E[X] - \mathbb E[X]^2\\
&= \frac{2(1-p)}{p^2} + \frac1p - \frac1{p^2}\\
&= \frac{1-p}{p^2}.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

\begin{align}E(X) &= \sum_{s \in S}p(s) \cdot X(s) &\text{ Expected Value of x}\\
Var(X) &= E(X^2) - E(X)^2 &\text{Variance of x}\end{align}

Comment: Just to clarify what exactly is X(s)?

Comment: X(s) is the value of the outcome. For example, if you say coins can be heads or tails, then we can say 0 for heads and 1 for tails. Then $E(X) = (0.5 \cdot 0) + (0.5 \cdot 1) = 0.5$, meaning it is equally likely to get tails as it is for heads.

Comment: How is the value of X(s) determined? It just seems arbitrary that you let tails=0. Couldn't it be say -1? But then that changes the expected value. In this case would we just solve so the expected value of one flip is p then?

Comment: Consider an example with dice. Then S, our sample space, is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Then for each $s \in S$, $p(s) = \frac16$. But $X(s)$ is different for each $s \in S$, because each face of the die has a different **value**. For one face, $X(s) = 6$, for another, $X(s) = 3$. etc.

Comment: but how is it decided with something like a coin, where values aren't explicitly mentioned

Comment: You can set them arbitrarily. So long as the probabilities for heads and tails are both 0.5, then the expected value will lie exactly halfway between the values for heads and tails, respectively. But for H/T coins, it is conventional to use [0,1].

Comment: and when the probabilities aren't 50/50 as in this case?